# How to resolve java.net.SocketException MESSAGE: Too many open files

Tags: sockets, tomcat, limit, file-descriptor, ulimit

We have a Struts2 web application running in Tomcat7 and MySQL5 database. After navigating on the site for a bit, we are getting the exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
```

If we restart Tomcat, it works again for some time, and then the problem respawn.

Can some one help me to get out of this issue ?

STACKTRACE:

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
 at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:387)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:361)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1185)
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:79)
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
```

Answer (score 1):

Socket connections are treated like files, and they use File Descriptor (FD), which is a limited resource. When a program (not necessarily *your* program, maybe is just Tomcat serving too much connections) open and close too many connections in a short span of time, you will get:

> java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

This is due to the fact that a connection, *after* is closed, can be in a TIME_WAIT state for a bit (60 seconds on Linux, 4 minutes on Windows), and hence keeping the FD locked. When you ran out of FDs, you get the exception, that basically means

> Too many socket connections open in a short span of time

The limit, different on each Operating System, can be examined with a command, eg. on Unix / Linux:

```
ulimit -n
```

Then simply raise the limit, eg. on Unix / Linux edit the file

> /etc/security/limits.conf

adding at the end of the file the following line:

```
USR hard nofile 13370 
USR soft nofile 13370
```

replacing `USR` with the user name used by Tomcat, and `13370` with the new limit you want to set.

You might need to do other operations, follow [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515463/how-to-increase-maximum-file-open-limit-ulimit-in-ubuntu) if the above change isn't enough.

Also [remember to reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot).