# Why Amazon Titan throws Elasticsearch exception?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan

I'm using Spark to write a heavy application requiring 50 machines on a cluster to work on reading/writing on the graph.

At the moment, I'm testing it locally, meaning that there 50 threads starting in parallel. Each one of them initializes the database connection.

For some reason, I get this error:

```
16/03/16 21:18:19 WARN state.meta: [Jacob "Jake" Fury] failed to find dangling indices
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp/searchindex/data/elasticsearch/nodes/32/indices: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:427)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.findAllIndices(NodeEnvironment.java:530)
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.local.state.meta.LocalGatewayMetaState.clusterChanged(LocalGatewayMetaState.java:245)
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.local.LocalGateway.clusterChanged(LocalGateway.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:188)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm not using ElasticSearch at all in the configuration file. and all my indexes are composites. Does Titan DynamoDB implementation uses it internally? How to solve this exception?

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to Titan's DynamoDB implementation but the error `Too many open files` is a fairly common problem with *nix os.

Dig up information on how to raise the number of open files in your OS and the problem will go away (e.g. [How to increase Neo4j's maximum file open limit (ulimit) in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515463/how-to-increase-maximum-file-open-limit-ulimit-in-ubuntu)).

Comment: Thanks. This will help solve the side effect of the main problem. But still, the remaining issue is, why ElasticSearch start when I never mentioned it in the config file of Titan.