# OS error load averages unobtainable greenlet celery stackoverflow

Tags: concurrency, celery, gevent

I am frequently running into this error.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuqS7.png)

This is happening when I am running celery worker with Gevent Thread.
This error starts coming frequently after its first incidence.

I am using
Python 2.7
Celery 4.0.2
OS Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

This is basically OS error stating that it is running out of file descriptors.
Celery is running 2000 tasks in parallel which need 4000 task descriptors.
Default limit of OS is (ulimit - n) 
Soft 1024
Hard 65000
Updating these limits resolved the issue. 
To update these limits follow steps on this link
[How to increase Neo4j's maximum file open limit (ulimit) in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515463/how-to-increase-neo4js-maximum-file-open-limit-ulimit-in-ubuntu)